# CSS working inline but not from stylesheet

Tags: css

I've read through all the other posts on this topic but non seemed to help.

When I have:

```
.tb-megamenu-submenu .dropdown-menu .mega-dropdown-menu .nav-child{
    left:50% !important;
}
```

It doesn't add the style to the element.

But If I use it inline it works:

```
<div data-class="increase-background-about" data-width="0" class="tb-megamenu-submenu increase-background-about dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu nav-child" style="left:50px">
```

I'm completely stumped and the other questions haven't helped.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the spaces and try. It should work!

```
.tb-megamenu-submenu.dropdown-menu.mega-dropdown-menu.nav-child{
    left:50% !important;
}
```

The issue with your styling is that all the classes you mentioned are for the same element.

So to target them you need to do it like I've done above - *without spaces*.
Your styling would work when these classes are descendants

i.e. *.tb-megamenu-submenu -> .dropdown-menu -> .mega-dropdown-menu -> .nav-child*

Arrow represents the parent-child relation.

Learn basics of CSS from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp).

Answer (score 1):

1. Your selector is wrong. That is actually looking for a `.nav-child` element, inside a `.mega-dropdown-menu`, inside a `.dropdown-menu`, inside a `.tb-megamenu-submenu.` You should remove the spaces in your selector:

   ```
   .tb-megamenu-submenu.dropdown-menu.mega-dropdown-menu.nav-child{
       left: 50%;
   }
   ```
2. Please do not use `!important`. It makes your code very hard to maintain. Instead, try to write more specific selectors (incidentally, this should be specific enough).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to specify your element through multiple classes right? But by putting spaces between the selector you are actually getting descendants:

```
.tb-megamenu-submenu
   . dropdown-menu
       .nav-child <- getting this element
```

To get the right result you should concotenate the `.classes` without spaces between, like:

```
.tb-megamenu-submenu.dropdown-menu.mega-dropdown-menu.nav-child { 
    left:50% !important; 
}
```